# Segmentation fault (core dumped) - strlcpy function C

Tags: c, undefined-behavior, c-strings, string-literals, function-definition

I have been building some basic C functions, but Im still not too experienced.

When coding **strlcpy** function I keep getting a **Segmentation fault (core dumped)** error. Thought it could have something to do with NUL-terminating strings but I keep getting the error when running.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <bsd/string.h>

unsigned int    ft_strlcpy(char *dst, char *src, unsigned int size)
{
    unsigned int i;
    unsigned int j;

    j = 0;
    while (src[j] != '\0')
        j++;
    
    if (size == 0)
        return (j);

    i = 0;
    while (i < (size - 1) && src[i] != '\0')
    {
        dst[i] = src[i];
        i++;
    }
    dst[i] = '\0';
    return (j);
}

int main()
{
    char *str;

    str = "byes";
    str[3] = '\0';
    printf("%s", str);
    printf("%u", ft_strlcpy("hello", str, 5));
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: You cannot write into a string literal, such as `"hello"`

Comment: It looks like you're passing `"hello"` as the destination string?  Have you tried using other pieces of memory - something allocated on the heap or the stack?

Comment: Look at the relationship between `j` and `size`: the later could be much larger than the first, and then you would access memory out of bounds.

Comment: when you pass string literal like you did, the compiler allocates it in the data read only section. **this section is read only**! hence the sig fault. if you want to edit (write) the string, allocate it on the stack (`char foo[24]`) or on the heap (with `malloc`)

Comment: True, thanks for the responses. Seem to be just an oversight.

Comment: Please do not add answers to the question body itself. Instead, you should add it as an answer. [Answering your own question is allowed and even encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declared a pointer to a string literal

```
char *str;

str = "byes";
```

String literals may not be changed. But you are trying to change the pointed string literal

```
str[3] = '\0';
```

that results in undefined behavior.

Remove this statement. The string literal already contains the terminating zero at index equal to 4.

Also in this call

```
printf("%u", ft_strlcpy("hello", str, 5));
```

you are again trying to change a string literal using the function `ft_strlcpy`. At this case it is the string literal `"hello"`.

Declare a character array as for example

```
char dsn[] = "hello";
```

and pass it to the function as an argument

```
printf("%u", ft_strlcpy( dsn, str, sizeof( dsn )));
```

Comment: @4386427 I was not attentive. I thought that the string literal is":bye".:)

Comment: @4386427 Maybe. It is not a standard function. But as for me it is logically inconsistent.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow The return value when `size` equals 0 seems to be the value of the string that was tried to be copied, as stated in the manual. Anyway, thanks for your response :)

Comment: @IkerTejero I noticed you "accepted" the answer. You could consider upvoting it as well.

Comment: @4386427 Not enough reputation unfortunately :(. Once I am able to do it, I will upvote it for sure.